# Getting SCRIPT1014: Invalid character in IE and Safari while handling GraphQL operations

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer, graphql, apollo-client

We are using Apollo client in Angular 1 to connect with GraphQL. Everything working fine in all browsers and mobiles except IE and Safari. Since we cannot replace the ` character in gql`${query}`, gql`${mutation}` from GraphQL operations, we are getting `SCRIPT1014: Invalid character`.

Anybody please suggest a solution for this problem

Thanks